# Cannot cast a generic type to list in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to do a simple test, in which I pass in two generic objects to a test function, see if they can be cast to `List<S>`, and further, check if the counts of the lists are equal.

The following code works:

```
private static void Test<T> (T obj1, T obj2) {
    if (typeof(T).IsGenericType) {
        var genericTypeParam1 = typeof(T).GetGenericArguments().First();
        Console.WriteLine(genericTypeParam1);

        // LINE MARKER 1
        // var obj1AsList = (obj1 as IEnumerable<genericTypeParam1>);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    Test(Enumerable.Range(0, 5).ToList(), Enumerable.Range(0, 5).ToList());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

But if I uncomment the line marked with `LINE MARKER 1`, I get the following error:

```
The type or namespace name 'genericTypeParam1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I do not know beforehand that Test will receive `List`s.  But my intention is to first check if `obj1` and `obj2` can be taken as lists, and then to compare

```
var obj1AsList = obj1 as List<genericTypeParam1>;
var obj2AsList = obj2 as List<genericTypeParam1>;
var flag = (obj1AsList != null) && (obj2AsList != null) && (obj1AsList.Count() == obj2AsList.Count());
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Test<Give Type Here>(Enumerable.Range(0, 5).ToList(), Enumerable.Range(0, 5).ToList()); You missed the type

Comment: @RonaldEstacion That's not a problem. It will be inferred by compiler.

Comment: In your sample code you indicate that you wanted to cast to `IEnumerable` instead of `IList`, is that correct? Only the latter has a `Count` property, which can be accessed by casting to the non-generic `Collections` interfaces. (See answer, below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the true goal is to ensure that both items can be cast to some generic list type, then just as-cast the objects into the non-generic `IList` interface. Then you can compare the count:

```
private static bool Test<T>(T obj1, T obj2)
{
    if (typeof(T).IsGenericType)
    {
        var obj1List = obj1 as System.Collections.IList;
        var obj2List = obj2 as System.Collections.IList;

        if (obj1List != null && obj2List != null && obj1List.Count == obj2List.Count)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you really want to use reflection it you might make something like this work:

```
if (typeof(T).IsGenericType) {
        var genericTypeParam1 = typeof(T).GetGenericArguments().First();
        Console.WriteLine(genericTypeParam1);

        // LINE MARKER 1
        // var obj1AsList = (obj1 as IEnumerable<genericTypeParam1>);
        var genericListType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(genericTypeParam1);

        Convert.ChangeType(obj1,genericListType);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I am using the first suggestion.  The second one throws an `InvalidCastException` at `Convert.ChangeType`, saying that `Object must implement IConvertible`.

Answer (score 4):

> I am trying to do a simple test, in which I pass in two objects to a test function, see if they can be cast to `List<S>`, and further, check if the counts of the lists are equal.

The correct way to do that is:

```
static bool Test<T>(object obj1, object obj2)
{
    List<T> list1 = obj1 as List<T>;
    List<T> list2 = obj2 as List<T>;
    return list1 != null && list2 != null && list1.Count == list2.Count;
}
...
bool result = Test<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 5).ToList(), Enumerable.Range(0, 5).ToList());
```

This takes two objects and a type, and returns true if the objects are equally-sized lists of that type.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed.  I have accepted nicolas' answer because it suggests a second method as well.  But I am basically using something very similar to your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Type provided as generic type parameter has to be known at compile time. You're trying to pass `Type` typed variable instead, and that's why you're getting compile type error.

You can make the fact, that only `List<T>` instances can be passed as method parameters check by compiler during compilation time:

```
private static void Test<T>(List<T> obj1, List<T> obj2)
{
    var flag = obj1 != null && obj2 != null && obj1.Count == obj2.Count;
}
```

If you want that test to be done during runtime you should use solution provided by Eric.